# Jbehave Ant Task

Tags: ant, jenkins, jbehave

I'm looking to introduce Jbehave in my project, and I am preparing a simple POC.
Using: jbehave 3.9.3, ant 1.9.2, IDE eclipse kepler.
I can successfully run the tests from within Eclipse (I've also annotated my test class with @RunWith(JUnitReportingRunner.class) ).

I have, however, some issues when I try running the same via ant.

this is the ant file I'm using:

```
    <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/bdd/jbtest"/>
    <property name="jbehave.version"  value="3.9.3"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="target" />
    </target>

    <target name="setup">
        <artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="test">
            <dependency groupId="org.jbehave" artifactId="jbehave-ant" version="${jbehave.version}"/>           
            <dependency groupId="org.jbehave" artifactId="jbehave-core" version="${jbehave.version}" classifier="resources" type="zip"/>           
            <dependency groupId="org.jbehave.site" artifactId="jbehave-site-resources" version="3.1.1" type="zip"/>           
        </artifact:dependencies>

        <mkdir dir="target" />
        <mkdir dir="target/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="target/lib" />
        <copy todir="target/lib">
            <fileset refid="dependency.fileset" />
            <mapper type="flatten" />
        </copy>
        <!--  copy todir="${src.dir}">
            <fileset dir="../core/src/main/java">       
            </fileset>
        </copy> -->
        <copy todir="target/classes">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.story" />
                <include name="**/*.properties" />
                <include name="**/*.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>



        <path id="story.classpath">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/bin" />
        </path>
        <classloader classpathref="story.classpath" />

        <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="story.classpath.unix" refid="story.classpath">
        </pathconvert>
        <echo>Using classpath: ${story.classpath.unix}</echo>

    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="setup">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="bin" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,source" includes="**/*.java,**/*.xml">
            <classpath refid="story.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="reports-resources" depends="setup">
        <unzip src="${org.jbehave:jbehave-core:zip:resources}" dest="${basedir}/target/jbehave/view/" />
        <unzip src="${org.jbehave.site:jbehave-site-resources:zip}" dest="${basedir}/target/jbehave/view/" />
    </target>


    <target name="run-stories-as-embeddables" depends="compile, reports-resources">
        <taskdef name="runStoriesAsEmbeddables" classname="org.jbehave.ant.RunStoriesAsEmbeddables" classpathref="story.classpath" />
        <runStoriesAsEmbeddables sourceDirectory="${src.dir}" includes="**/Myjb.java" excludes="**/examples*" batch="false" ignoreFailureInStories="true" ignoreFailureInView="true" generateViewAfterStories="true" 
            systemproperties="java.awt.headless=true,project.dir=${basedir}" />
    </target>


    <target name="run-stories-as-paths" depends="compile, reports-resources" >
        <taskdef name="runStoriesAsPaths" classname="org.jbehave.ant.RunStoriesAsPaths" classpathref="story.classpath" />
        <runStoriesAsPaths sourceDirectory="${src.dir}" 
                includes="**/*.story" batch="false" ignoreFailureInStories="true" ignoreFailureInView="true" generateViewAfterStories="true" 
                systemproperties="java.awt.headless=true,project.dir=${basedir}" 
        >    
        </runStoriesAsPaths>                

    </target>

    <target name="stepdoc" depends="compile">
        <taskdef name="reportStepdocs" classname="org.jbehave.ant.ReportStepdocs" classpathref="story.classpath" />
        <reportStepdocs embedderClass="org.jbehave.examples.core.CoreEmbedder" />

                 <taskdef name="reportRenderer" classname="org.jbehave.ant.ReportRendererTask"  classpathref="story.classpath" />
    <reportRenderer outputDirectory="${basedir}/target/jbehave"
      formats="txt,html" templateProperties="defaultFormats=stats" 
      ignoreFailure="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="run-stories-as-paths,stepdoc" />

</project>
```

**issue #1: I can't specify the format**

```
run-stories-as-paths:
[runStoriesAsPaths] Running stories as paths using embedder Embedder[storyMapper=StoryMapper,storyRunner=StoryRunner,embedderMonitor=AntEmbedderMonitor,classLoader=EmbedderClassLoader[urls=[],parent=java.net.URLClassLoader@1a8fa0f0],embedderControls=UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=true,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]],embedderFailureStrategy=<null>,configuration=org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration@5556d74f,candidateSteps=<null>,stepsFactory=<null>,metaFilters=<null>,systemProperties={java.awt.headless=true, project.dir=D:danielewsjbtest},executorService=<null>,executorServiceCreated=false,storyManager=<null>]
[runStoriesAsPaths] Found story paths: [Example.story, Sample.story]
[runStoriesAsPaths] Processing system properties {java.awt.headless=true, project.dir=D:danielewsjbtest}
[runStoriesAsPaths] System property 'java.awt.headless' set to 'true'
[runStoriesAsPaths] System property 'project.dir' set to 'D:danielewsjbtest'
[runStoriesAsPaths] Using controls UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=true,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]]
[runStoriesAsPaths] Generating reports view to 'D:\daniele\ws\jbtest\target\jbehave' using formats '[]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
[runStoriesAsPaths] Reports view generated with 0 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 0 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
```

I did not find a way to pass the format as I'm doing in the java class and that get's ignored, so it does not generate any report.

**issue #2 story finding exception**

when I run

```
ant -f jb_ant.xml -lib lib run-stories-as-paths
```

just after the output shown above, I get an exception

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\daniele\ws\jbtest\jb_ant.xml:74: org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path 'Example.story' not found by class loader EmbedderClassLoader[urls=[],parent=java.net.URLClassLoader@1a8fa0f0]
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.resourceAsStream(LoadFromClasspath.java:44)
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.loadResourceAsText(LoadFromClasspath.java:29)
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.loadStoryAsText(LoadFromClasspath.java:38)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.storyOfPath(StoryRunner.java:192)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.storyOfPath(StoryManager.java:49)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runningStoriesAsPaths(StoryManager.java:101)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStories(StoryManager.java:78)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:203)
    at org.jbehave.ant.RunStoriesAsPaths.execute(RunStoriesAsPaths.java:16)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

which is puzzling me because jbehave had just listed the found the story while executing the task.

I can post the both the Java classes and stories if this may help diagnose the problem.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found an answer to these issues:

- the org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound exception was resolved by implementing a StoryFinder Class (code below)
- to generate the reports, I had to implement an Embedder class (code below) and specify the formats there (apparently there is no way to pass this directly to the Ant tasks.

Hope this helps anyone else with similar problems.

**StoryFinder**

```
package jbtest;


import org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder;
import java.util.*;

public class MyStoryFinder extends StoryFinder {
    @Override
    protected List<String> scan(String basedir, List<String> includes,
            List<String> excludes) {
        //List<String> defaultStories = super.scan(basedir, includes, excludes);
        //String myStories = System.getProperty("com.sarang.stories");
        return Arrays.asList("jbtest/Example.story,jbtest/Sample.story".split(","));
    }
}
```

**Embedder**

```
package jbtest;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder;
import org.jbehave.core.embedder.EmbedderControls;
import org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations;
import org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath;
import org.jbehave.core.parsers.RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.CrossReference;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.SilentStepMonitor;

public class MyEmbedder extends Embedder {

    @Override
    public EmbedderControls embedderControls() {
        return new EmbedderControls().doIgnoreFailureInStories(true).doIgnoreFailureInView(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        Class<? extends MyEmbedder> embedderClass = this.getClass();      
           Properties viewResources = new Properties();
            viewResources.put("decorateNonHtml", "true");

           return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
             .useStoryReporterBuilder(  
                 new StoryReporterBuilder()
                 .withDefaultFormats()
                .withViewResources(viewResources).withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.HTML, Format.XML)
                .withFailureTrace(true)
                ) ;
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new ExampleSteps(), new SampleSteps());
    }

}
```

Then I modified the Ant task as follows:

```
    <target name="run-stories-as-paths" depends="compile, reports-resources" >
    <taskdef name="runStoriesAsPaths" classname="org.jbehave.ant.RunStoriesAsPaths" classpathref="story.classpath" />
    <runStoriesAsPaths 
            sourceDirectory="${src.dir}" 
            includes="**/*.story" 
            ignoreFailureInStories="true" 
            ignoreFailureInView="true" 
            generateViewAfterStories="true" 
            storyfinderclass="jbtest.MyStoryFinder"
        verbosefailures="true"
        embedderclass="jbtest.MyEmbedder"
            >    
    </runStoriesAsPaths>
    </target>
```